# B ⊆ A rules in discrete maths

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a few questions about subsets. Assume we have

$A =\{ \{1, 2, 3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{a, b\} \}$

$B = \{ \{a ,b\}, \{1, 2\} \}$

1. Then $B \subseteq A$ is false because $B$ contains $\{1,2\}$ which is not exactly in $A$ whereas there is: $\{1,2,3\}$ Can you explain the "special" cases $B \not \subseteq A$?
2. Is $B \in A$ and why?

Comment: (1) What special cases? (2) Obviously not: is $\{\{a,b\},\{1,2\}\}$ listed as an element of $A$?

Comment: An analogy I often used that might help with the answers others have given is to think of a set as a trash can. In the case of your sets $A$ and $B,$ these are trash cans that contain other trash cans. In particular, (identical copies of) the trash can $\{a,b\},$ which contains the two pieces of trash $a$ and $b,$ is inside each of the trash cans $A$ and $B.$ Also, the trash can $\{1,2\}$ is in the trash can $B,$ but not in the trash can $A,$ so $B$ is not a subset of $A$ (because not all objects in trash can $B$ are in trash can $A).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No B is not an element of A.  B is a set of sets. A is a set of sets.

{1,2} is not "not exactly in A".  It's not in A.

Moreover for a set C={a,b,1,2,c}, is B a subset of C?

The answer is no. C contains elements a,b,1,2,c. It's cardinality is 5.  B contains elements  {a,b} and {1,2}. It's cardinality is 2.

I would highly recommend the free for download "Book of Proof" by Richard Hammack.  It has a nice thorough explanation of sets early on with lots of explained examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome. And check out the book

Answer (score 0):

So you need to know the precise meanings of these symbols.
The subset, for example $A\subseteq B$ would mean that every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$.  You can picture this as $A$ being "in" $B$, although the equal allows for the possibility that $A=B$.

[image] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset)

The element, for example what you have with $B \in A$ means that the entirety of $B$ is one element in the set $A$.  That means in your case $A$ would have to have as one of its elements **{{a,b},{1,2}}**

Answer (score 0):

I think you are being confused because the elements of the sets are themselves other sets.  If the elements were other things there'd be no problem.

Let V = {1,2,3}

Let W = {2,3}

Let X = {a,b}

Let Y = {1,2}

Then A = {V, W, X} and B = {X,Y}.  Then B has the element Y and A does not.  So B is not a subset.  That's all there is to it.

Is $B \in A$.  Well... no.  A contains the elements W,X,Y.  B = {X,Y} $\ne$ W.  B $\ne$ X and B $\ne$ Y.  So B is not an element of A.

Where many people get confused that the numbers 1,2 are in Y and the numbers 1,2 are in V and so somehow the *set* {1,2} must be in the V and therefore in the set A.    This is ... confusion.  The numbers 1,2 are not the same thing as the *set* {1,2}.  So although Y= {1,2} $\subset$ {1,2,3} = V and $V \in A$, $V \not \subset A$.  $Y \not \in A$.  The elements of a set and the sets themselves are simply different things.  {V} $\subset$ A because $V \in A$ but {V} $\ne$ V.  {V} is a set *containing* the set {1,2}.  V *is* the set {1,2}, or in other words a set containing 1,2.

Likewise $1 \in V$ and $2 \in V$ because 1 and 2 are members of the set V.  $1 \not \in \{V\}$ and $2 \not \in \{V\}$ because {V} has only *one* element and that element is V.  1 $\ne$ V and 2 $\ne$ V.  They are completely different things.